# Set "50.0" at default value instead of "50"

Tags: c++, mfc, textbox, double

I want to display "50.0" in one of my edit text boxes, but it keeps showing "50".

I have declared my variable as double and set my default value as "50.0", but when I run the application, it shows "50". This is how I have done the coding.

```
double x;
.
.

x = 50.0;
.
.

DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_TextBox1, x);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Do let me know if i need to give more information too.

Comment: `x` is still 50 even if you use redundant leading and trailing zeros. Not my area of expertise but my guess is that there's some way of specifying the number *format* in the edit text box.

Comment: Sounds about right. In that case is there a way in which i can make the edit box only accept "double"?

Comment: There probably is a way of allowing a number to 1 decimal place, yes. Probably a matter of trawling through the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure what `DDX_Text` exactly does, but it has an overload for a `CString`, which seems to be some custom string class by Microsoft. Maybe you can format the value and then load it as `CString`?

Comment: You probbaly need to write your own custom `MYDDX_Text` function. Copy the code  of `DDX_Text` (you have the MFC source code) and adapt as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these options:

Option 1:   SetDlgItemText(IDC_TextBox1, L"50.0");

Option 2: In the dynamic data exchange, the control variable may be taken as CString instead of int.

```
              CString str_; // member variable

              DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_TextBox1, str_); // DDX declaration

              double d = 50.0;
              str_.Format(L"%5.1lf", d); // assignment
```

Comment: Third option: write your own  DDX_Text function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to do it using the 2nd option combined with 
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_TextBox1,str_);